# Mongoose can't query only a database

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I'm facing a Mongoose's strange behaviour.

Let's analyse this simple stupid code.

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1/sodatest', {
    useMongoClient: true
});

var db = mongoose.connection;

var OriginalSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    addedd: Date,
    endPoint: Object,
    inserted: Number,
    total: Number
});


var OtherTestSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    what: String,
    modified_at: Date
});


var EndPointInTheDb = mongoose.model('aaa', OriginalSchema);

db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection error:'));
db.once('open', function () {
    console.log("we are connected!");
});


EndPointInTheDb.find({}, (err: String, exit: any) => {
    console.log("Errore : " + err)
    console.log(exit)
});
```

It fails and return

```
we are connected!
*********************
Error : null
[]
*********************
```

It fails because the collection "aaa" has 15 elements.

If I change the db "sodatest" with any other ( except for another one with a lowercase name )  and 'aaa' with another collection name, it does't care if I use the correct case, it returns a correct result.

```
we are connected!
*********************
Error  : null
[ { _id: 59f76203592b426a16b8b32f,
    modified_at: 2017-10-30T17:31:47.622Z,
    last_position: 5,
    what: 'CONTATOREGEOKEY',
    __v: 0 } ]
*********************
```

(it works also with multiple elements)

I've tried to copy the db in another one,

```
db.copyDatabase("sodatest","Prova14")
```

with a name with at least an uppercase char (Prova14), but again no result.

I've checked for hours if I've misspelled a name, but really, I'm sure of it.

I can't understand why it works with any other db ( 14 others with heterogeneous schema) also if I use a schema ("OtherTestSchema" ) that does not match with the collection real schema.... but not with sodatest.

Any Idea ?

Comment: You can turn on debug mode with `mongoose.set('debug', true);`. You might find something with it.

Comment: Mongoose: aaas.find({}, { fields: {} }) this is the only row of the "debug", it is the same for the working and not working db. I

Comment: Can it be realted to the fact that I've imported them using MongoBooster ? But using it I can query the collection without any problem. "db.aaa.find({})" works fine.

Answer (score 1):

Mongoose automatically adds an 's' at the end of the collection name if one is not provided. For Example:

```
// This will create a collection called 'aaas' since 'aaa' is passed as the 
// model name
var EndPointInTheDb = mongoose.model('aaa', OriginalSchema);

// This is how you declare your collection name with a custom collection 'aaa'
var CorrectEndPointInTheDbToCollection = mongoose.model('aaa', OriginalSchema, 'aaa');

CorrectEndPointInTheDbToCollection.find({}, function(err, docs){
    console.log(docs)
})
```

So the initializer for mongoose is mongoose.model('model name', Schema, 'optional collection name'). Highly recommend you pass in the collection name so you know it's pointing to the right collection